# How to convert regions in figure into graph (nodes and edges) structure

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

I am solving a problem asked in `IOI 2007 - FLOOD`, which is also there on `SPOJ`.

http://www.spoj.com/OI/problems/FLOOD/
http://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/online-study-material/problems/flood.php

I thought a lot for a solution. Later I came to know that -

```
Step 0: Converting a region into a node and 
Step 1: Connecting two nodes with edges only if corresponding regions share at least a segment. 
Step 2: And then running a BFS on this will simplify the problem.
```

Still I am not able to think about the end to end solution, but then I thought lets try with step 0 & 1.
There also I failed. If there is an image in front, I can easily see the regions, but not programmatically.

```
The input would be end co-ordinate points of segments.
```

I am attaching an image for reference.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are of course many different ways for solving this problem. One possible approach is to use techniques from the field of [Computational Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_geometry). In particular the following two concepts are helpful:

- [Doubly-connected edge list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_connected_edge_list) (DCEL): This kind of data structure is commonly used when dealing with planar graphs. The basic idea is to extend each edge to hold a reference to the regions (also called "faces") that are next to the edge.

  One approach for implementing this would be to split each undirected edge into two directed edges, one for each direction. Each directed edge then can be extended to hold one reference to the region on its right (from the perspective of the starting vertex of the directed edge). Also, it is helpful to extend each edge to store a reference to the reverse edge (sometimes called "peer" or "twin" edge).
- [Sweep lining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm): This type of algorithm is widely used when dealing with planar structures. Conceptually, it works by moving a "sweep line" across the plane, while maintaining some intermediate result. Every time an object on the plane is hit by the sweep line, the intermediate result is updated based on that object. When the final object has been swept, the final result should be derivable from the intermediate result.

  In more practical terms, this is usually implemented by sorting the input points by their coordinate (i.e. first by the y-coordinate, and if two points have the same y-coordinate, then by their x-coordinate). The "sweeping" is then done by iterating over the sorted points.

To give you more reference, I'm familiar with these techniques from the construction of [Voronoi diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram). In particular, if you study [Fortune's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune%27s_algorithm), you will see that it has some similarities with the approach I'm describing here (i.e. it also uses DCEL and sweep lining). Also, I enjoyed reading this [book](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783540779735) on Computational Geometry, which describes these techniques in more detail.

I will describe how to apply these techniques to the FLOOD problem in the sections below. The full code is at the end of the answer.

### Data structure

To avoid having to deal with pointers, I will mostly used indices to represent references between objects. I'm using the following aliases to make clear if a given index is supposed to be an index to a vertex, edge or face:

```cpp
using v_index_t = uint32_t;
using e_index_t = uint32_t;
using f_index_t = uint32_t;

constexpr e_index_t NULL_EDGE = 0;
constexpr f_index_t OUTER_PLANE = 0;
```

Each vertex stores its position and which edges are incident to the vertex.
Since the edges of the input graph are axis-aligned, each vertex can have at most four edges. For this reason, I'm using a fixed-size array with four elements, for each of the four directions. If a vertex does not have an edge for some direction, the special index `NULL_EDGE` is used.

```cpp
struct Vertex {
  int x;
  int y;

  std::array<e_index_t, 4> incident;
};
```

The edges are stored following the DCEL approach. Each edge is directed and holds a reference to the face on its right and a reference to its peer edge:

```cpp
struct Edge {
  v_index_t a;
  v_index_t b;

  e_index_t peer;
  f_index_t faceRight;
};
```

Each face holds the list of edges that enclose the face:

```cpp
struct Face {
  std::vector<e_index_t> edges;
};
```

The full graph holds a list of vertices, edges and faces:

```cpp
struct Graph {
  std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
  std::vector<Edge> edges;
  std::vector<Face> faces;
};
```

### Algorithm

Once you have constructed the input graph, the basic approach for constructing the faces would then be:

- Sort the vertices by their coordinate.
- Initialize a [union-find data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure), that initially assigns each vertex to its own partition. The partitions are used to indicate which vertices can reach each other.
- Iterate over the sorted vertices. For every vertex, check the directions of the edges starting at that vertex. For every left-wards or down-wards edge, check if the current vertex and the end-point of that edge are in the same partition (using the find-operation of the union-find data structure).

  - If yes, the edge closes an inner loop (since vertices are in the same partition if they can reach each other). Create a new face. Starting at the current edge, follow the edges enclosing the face by always taking the right-most successor edge. For each visited edge, set the DCEL reference for the right-wards face to point to the newly created face.
  - If no, join the two partitions in the union-find data structure, to indicate that the two vertices can reach each other (and thereby every vertex known to be reachable from one of the vertices can also be reached from the other).

Assuming you have implemented a helper function `getSortedVertices` for sorting the vertices, a helper class `VertexPartition` that implements the union-find data structure and a helper function `applyFaceRightwards` that travels along the edges enclosing a face by always taking the rightmost successor edge, the main routine for identifying the faces could look as follows:

```cpp
void Graph::createFaceGraph() {

  // Sort vertices by coordinate
  auto indices{getSortedVertices()};

  // Initialize union-find data structure with one partition for each vertex.
  VertexPartition partition(vertices.size());

  // Sweep over the sorted vertices
  for (v_index_t current : indices) {

    // Check leftwards and downwards edges. The rightwards and upwards edges
    // are handled from the vertex at the other side.
    for (Direction direction : {Direction::Left, Direction::Down}) {
      e_index_t edgeIndex{vertices[current].incident[direction]};

      if (edgeIndex == NULL_EDGE) {
        continue;
      }

      Edge &edge{edges[edgeIndex]};
      v_index_t other = edge.other(current);

      // Use the union-find structure to join the partitions of the current
      // vertex and the vertex at the other side of the edge.
      bool success = partition.joinPartitions(other, current);

      // If the partitions were joined successfully, no action is needed.
      if (success) {
        continue;
      }

      // If the vertices were already in the same partition,
      // a loop has been found. Create a new face and travel rightwards
      // from the current edge to apply the face index to all edge
      // that are enclosing the face.
      faces.emplace_back();
      f_index_t faceIndex = faces.size() - 1;
      applyFaceRightwards(other, current, faceIndex);
    }
  }

  // Add all unprocessed edges to the outer plane.
  for (size_t i = 1; i < edges.size(); i++) {
    if (edges[i].faceRight == OUTER_PLANE) {
      faces[OUTER_PLANE].edges.push_back(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Once you have constructed the face graph, you can then use BFS on the face graph, as you described in your question. For each face, you would iterate over the edges enclosing the face. For each edge, you would obtain the twin edge and add the face referenced by the twin edge to the BFS queue. You would record the BFS rank for each face. To find the walls that would have collapsed during the flooding, you would then identify the edges that are in between faces with differing BFS rank.

Note that the algorithm given above has one limitation: It does not actually construct the full face graph, in that it does not take loop nesting into account. Consider the following example:

[image]

The full face-graph would have one vertex for the outer plane, then one vertex for the region between the first and the second square, and then one vertex for the region in the inner square:

[image]

However, the algorithm given above does not check that the inner rectangle is enclosed by the outer rectangle. Instead, it assigns both rectangles as being enclosed by the outer plane:

[image]

So if you really wanted to construct the full face graph, this result would be wrong. You could fix this for example by adding a second sweep pass that keeps track of the face nesting. However, for the FLOOD problem this is not needed: For the final result we are not interested in the specific BFS level, but only in whether there is a BFS level difference between adjacent faces. To get this information, it does not matter if the face of the inner rectangle is attached to the face of the outer rectangle or to the outer plane. To put it into more practical terms: If a structure is completely enclosed inside another structure, the walls of the inner structure will break in the same order as when the structure is moved to the outer plane. When moving the structure to the outer plane, its walls would of course break sooner, but the order in which they break is the same. Therefore the final result does not change.

This saves us from having to write additional code to handle the face nesting and allows us to keep the code more compact.

Full code (which is 100%'d by SPOJ):

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

/**
 * Aliases to make it clear which object type is referenced by an index.
 */
using v_index_t = uint32_t;
using e_index_t = uint32_t;
using f_index_t = uint32_t;

/**
 * The edge index 0 is used to indicate "no edge".
 */
constexpr e_index_t NULL_EDGE = 0;

/**
 * The face index 0 is used to indicate the outer plane.
 */
constexpr f_index_t OUTER_PLANE = 0;

/**
 * The four direction used in the axis-aligned input graph.
 */
enum Direction { Up, Right, Down, Left };

/**
 * Data structure for a vertex.
 */
struct Vertex {

  /**
   * Position of the vertex.
   */
  const int x;
  const int y;

  /**
   * The edges incident to the vertex in the four direction.
   * If the vertex does not have an edge for some direction, NULL_EDGE is used.
   */
  std::array<e_index_t, 4> incident;

  /**
   * Create a new vertex at the given position.
   */
  Vertex(int x, int y);

  /**
   * Get the direction that vertex "to" is, relative to this vertex.
   */
  Direction getDirection(const Vertex &to) const;
};

/**
 * Data structure for an edge, using the DCEL approach
 */
struct Edge {

  /**
   * Starting vertex of the edge.
   */
  v_index_t a;

  /**
   * End vertex of the edge.
   */
  v_index_t b;

  /**
   * The peer edge, meaning the directed edge b->a.
   */
  e_index_t peer;

  /**
   * The face to the right of the edge
   * (from the perspective of the starting vertex).
   */
  f_index_t faceRight{OUTER_PLANE};

  /**
   * Default-constructed, needed for the NULL_EDGE.
   */
  Edge() = default;

  /**
   * Create a new edge a->b.
   */
  Edge(v_index_t a, v_index_t b);

  /**
   * Get the other vertex of the edge. If "from" is "a" then "b" is returned,
   * if "from" is "b" then "a" is returned.
   */
  v_index_t other(v_index_t from) const;
};

/**
 * Data structure for a face (meaning a region in the plane).
 */
struct Face {
  /**
   * List of edges that enclose this face.
   */
  std::vector<e_index_t> edges;
};

/**
 * Data structure for a graph.
 */
struct Graph {

  /**
   * List of vertices in the graph.
   */
  std::vector<Vertex> vertices;

  /**
   * List of edges in the graph.
   */
  std::vector<Edge> edges;

  /**
   * List of faces in the graph.
   */
  std::vector<Face> faces;

  /**
   * Create the empty graph.
   */
  Graph();

  /**
   * Add an undirected edge a<->b.
   */
  void add_edge(v_index_t a, v_index_t b);

  /**
   * Get the right-most edge that follows the edge parent->current.
   */
  e_index_t getRightMostEdge(v_index_t current, v_index_t parent);

  /**
   * Sort the vertices by their coordinate.
   */
  std::vector<v_index_t> getSortedVertices();

  /**
   * Travel right-wards along the successor edges of from->to.
   * Apply the faceIndex to each visited edge.
   */
  void applyFaceRightwards(v_index_t to, v_index_t from, f_index_t faceIndex);

  /**
   * Use sweep-lining to construct the face graph.
   */
  void createFaceGraph();

  /**
   * Use BFS on the face graph to identify which collapsing walls.
   */
  void findCollapsedWalls();
};

/**
 * Union-find data structure.
 */
struct VertexPartition {

  /**
   * Maps each vertex to the representive of its partition.
   */
  std::vector<v_index_t> parent;

  /**
   * Tracks the rank of each vertex in the union-find tree structure.
   */
  std::vector<int> rank;

  /**
   * Initialize the union-find structure such that each vertex
   * is in its own partition.
   */
  VertexPartition(size_t size);

  /**
   * Find the representive of the partition in which the vertex is contained.
   */
  v_index_t findPartition(v_index_t vertex);

  /**
   * Join the partitions containing the vertices a and b.
   */
  bool joinPartitions(v_index_t a, v_index_t b);
};

Vertex::Vertex(int x, int y) : x{x}, y{y}, incident{} {}

Direction Vertex::getDirection(const Vertex &to) const {
  bool left = (x > to.x);
  bool right = (x < to.x);
  bool up = (y < to.y);
  bool down = (y > to.y);

  if (!up && !down) {
    if (right) {
      return Direction::Right;
    } else if (left) {
      return Direction::Left;
    }
  }

  if (!left && !right) {
    if (up) {
      return Direction::Up;
    } else if (down) {
      return Direction::Down;
    }
  }

  throw std::runtime_error{"Invalid alignment!"};
}

Edge::Edge(v_index_t a, v_index_t b) : a{a}, b{b} {}

v_index_t Edge::other(v_index_t from) const {
  if (from == a) {
    return b;
  }

  if (from == b) {
    return a;
  }

  throw std::runtime_error{"Vertex not incident to edge!"};
}

VertexPartition::VertexPartition(size_t size) : parent(size), rank(size) {
  std::iota(parent.begin(), parent.end(), 0);
}

v_index_t VertexPartition::findPartition(v_index_t vertex) {
  // Pass 1: Find the representive of the partition containing vertex
  v_index_t top = vertex;
  while (parent[top] != top) {
    top = parent[top];
  }

  // Pass 2: Compress path to speed up future queries.
  while (parent[vertex] != vertex) {
    v_index_t next = parent[vertex];
    parent[vertex] = top;
    vertex = next;
  }

  return top;
}

bool VertexPartition::joinPartitions(v_index_t a, v_index_t b) {
  v_index_t aParent = findPartition(a);
  v_index_t bParent = findPartition(b);

  if (aParent == bParent) {
    return false;
  }

  // Make the representive with maximum rank the representive of the joined
  // partition.
  int aParentRank = rank[aParent];
  int bParentRank = rank[bParent];

  if (aParentRank < bParentRank) {
    v_index_t tmp = aParentRank;
    aParentRank = bParentRank;
    bParentRank = tmp;
  }

  parent[bParent] = aParent;
  if (aParentRank == bParentRank) {
    rank[aParent] += 1;
  }

  return true;
}

Graph::Graph() {
  faces.emplace_back(); // Create default face, representing the outer plane.
  edges.emplace_back(); // Create null edge, so that index 0 means "no edge".
}

void Graph::add_edge(v_index_t a, v_index_t b) {
  edges.emplace_back(a, b);
  edges.emplace_back(b, a);

  e_index_t indexAtoB = edges.size() - 2;
  e_index_t indexBtoA = edges.size() - 1;

  edges[indexAtoB].peer = indexBtoA;
  edges[indexBtoA].peer = indexAtoB;

  Direction directionAtoB{vertices[a].getDirection(vertices[b])};
  Direction directionBtoA{vertices[b].getDirection(vertices[a])};

  vertices[a].incident[directionAtoB] = indexAtoB;
  vertices[b].incident[directionBtoA] = indexBtoA;
}

e_index_t Graph::getRightMostEdge(v_index_t parent, v_index_t current) {
  Direction direction{vertices[current].getDirection(vertices[parent])};

  // Check the directions following the current direction in counter-clockwise
  // order. Note that in the last iteration of the loop, the direction
  // current->parent is checked. 
  for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    int directionAsIntShifted{direction - i};
    if (directionAsIntShifted < 0) {
      directionAsIntShifted += 4;
    }
    Direction directionShifted{static_cast<Direction>(directionAsIntShifted)};
    e_index_t edge{vertices[current].incident[directionShifted]};

    if (edge != NULL_EDGE) {
      return edge;
    }
  }

  return NULL_EDGE;
}

std::vector<v_index_t> Graph::getSortedVertices() {
  std::vector<v_index_t> indices(vertices.size());
  std::iota(indices.begin(), indices.end(), 0);

  auto key = [&](v_index_t i, v_index_t j) -> bool {
    return (vertices[i].y < vertices[j].y) ||
           (vertices[i].y == vertices[j].y && vertices[i].x < vertices[j].x);
  };

  std::sort(indices.begin(), indices.end(), key);

  return indices;
}

void Graph::applyFaceRightwards(v_index_t current, v_index_t parent,
                                f_index_t faceIndex) {
  for (;;) {
    e_index_t edgeIndex{getRightMostEdge(parent, current)};

    if (!edgeIndex) {
      break;
    }

    Edge &edge{edges[edgeIndex]};
    v_index_t next{edge.other(current)};

    if (edge.faceRight != OUTER_PLANE) {
      break;
    }

    edge.faceRight = faceIndex;
    faces[faceIndex].edges.push_back(edgeIndex);

    parent = current;
    current = next;
  }
}

void Graph::createFaceGraph() {

  // Sort vertices by coordinate
  auto indices{getSortedVertices()};

  // Initialize union-find data structure with one partition for each vertex.
  VertexPartition partition(vertices.size());

  // Sweep over the sorted vertices
  for (v_index_t current : indices) {

    // Check leftwards and downwards edges. The rightwards and upwards edges
    // are handled from the vertex at the other side.
    for (Direction direction : {Direction::Left, Direction::Down}) {
      e_index_t edgeIndex{vertices[current].incident[direction]};

      if (edgeIndex == NULL_EDGE) {
        continue;
      }

      Edge &edge{edges[edgeIndex]};
      v_index_t other = edge.other(current);

      // Use the union-find structure to join the partitions of the current
      // vertex and the vertex at the other side of the edge.
      bool success = partition.joinPartitions(other, current);

      // If the partitions were joined successfully, no action is needed.
      if (success) {
        continue;
      }

      // If the vertices were already in the same partition,
      // a loop has been found. Create a new face and travel rightwards
      // from the current edge to apply the face index to all edge
      // that are enclosing the face.
      faces.emplace_back();
      f_index_t faceIndex = faces.size() - 1;
      applyFaceRightwards(other, current, faceIndex);
    }
  }

  // Add all unprocessed edges to the outer plane.
  for (size_t i = 1; i < edges.size(); i++) {
    if (edges[i].faceRight == OUTER_PLANE) {
      faces[OUTER_PLANE].edges.push_back(i);
    }
  }
}

void Graph::findCollapsedWalls() {

  // Perform BFS on face graph
  std::queue<f_index_t> queue{};
  std::vector<bool> visited(faces.size());
  std::vector<int> rank(faces.size());

  auto processFace = [&](f_index_t next, int nextRank) {
    if (visited[next]) {
      return;
    }

    queue.push(next);
    visited[next] = true;
    rank[next] = nextRank;
  };

  processFace(OUTER_PLANE, 0);

  while (!queue.empty()) {
    f_index_t current{queue.front()};
    queue.pop();

    int nextRank = rank[current] + 1;

    for (e_index_t edge : faces[current].edges) {
      e_index_t peer = edges[edge].peer;
      processFace(edges[peer].faceRight, nextRank);
    }
  }

  // Check which edges are next to faces with equal BFS rank
  auto isWallStanding = [&](e_index_t i) {
    e_index_t j = edges[i].peer;

    return rank[edges[i].faceRight] == rank[edges[j].faceRight];
  };

  // Print the final result. Since the edge list contains each edge
  // twice, once for each direction, we skip over every second edge.
  // We also skip the NULL_EDGE.
  size_t wallCount = 0;
  for (size_t i = 2; i < edges.size(); i += 2) {
    if (isWallStanding(i)) {
      wallCount++;
    }
  }

  std::cout << wallCount << std::endl;
  for (size_t i = 2; i < edges.size(); i += 2) {
    if (isWallStanding(i)) {
      std::cout << i / 2 << std::endl;
    }
  }
}

int main() {

  Graph graph{};

  // Read input graph from stdin
  size_t corners{};
  std::cin >> corners;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < corners; i++) {
    int x;
    int y;
    std::cin >> x >> y;
    graph.vertices.emplace_back(x, y);
  }

  size_t walls{};
  std::cin >> walls;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < walls; i++) {
    size_t indexA;
    size_t indexB;
    std::cin >> indexA >> indexB;
    graph.add_edge(indexA - 1, indexB - 1);
  }

  graph.createFaceGraph();
  graph.findCollapsedWalls();

  return 0;
}
```